# Change URL of the windows for every different Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single page html code with 3 different Tabs in that.I have a requirement of chaining the URL for each tab.

I have seen some resources for changing the browser history using `windows.history.pushState()`.But as far as I know It only changes changing with `#extra-path`.

But I am trying to achieve something like:

> for tab1 ..  mybasedomain.com/tab1
>
> for tab2 ..  mybasedomain.com/tab2

How do I achieve it?Can I achieve it using JavaScript, jQuery?

My code structure:

```
<section id="features">
    <header>
        <div class="features-switcher">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="tab-links">
                    <li>
                        <a class="active" href="#tab1">
                            <span>tab one</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li >
                        <a class="" href="#tab2">
                            <span>tab two</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="" href="#tab3">
                            <span>tab three</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab--active">
        <section class="container">
            <h2> content of tab 1</h2>
        <hr>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab--inactive">
        <section class="container">
            <h2> content of tab 2</h2>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab--inactive">
        <section class="container">
            <h2> content of tab 3</h2>
        </section>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript, no need to jQuery. Look into HTML5 Push State.

Comment: Yeah I tired it is only adding extra path to existing URL as far as I know.Will it directly change the URL.

Comment: try this example .. https://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/c9s8ojd2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `history.replaceState()`

```js
$(".tab-links a").click(function(e) {
  var active = this.href.slice(-5)
  , link = active.slice(1);
  console.log(active, link)
  $(".tab-content [id^=tab]").hide();
  $(active).show();
  history.replaceState(null, link
    , location.href.slice(-1) === "/" 
    ? location.href + "/" + link 
    : link
  )
})
```

```css
.tab--inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<section id="features">
  <header>
    <div class="features-switcher">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="tab-links">
          <li>
            <a class="active" href="#tab1">
              <span>tab one</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="" href="#tab2">
              <span>tab two</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="" href="#tab3">
              <span>tab three</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </header>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab--active">
      <section class="container">
        <h2> content of tab 1</h2>
        <hr>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab--inactive">
      <section class="container">
        <h2> content of tab 2</h2>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab--inactive">
      <section class="container">
        <h2> content of tab 3</h2>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Tried but giving an error : `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///home/username/workspace/features/tab2' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.`

Comment: See OP at _"for tab1 .. mybasedomain.com/tab1"_ , _"for tab2 .. mybasedomain.com/tab2"_ ? `file:` protocol can be more restrictive than `http:` protocol. Which browser tried at ? chrome / chromium ?

Comment: Yeah , for now I am testing locally in chrome.Will it work in production then ?

Comment: Try with domain similar to described at OP ? , at `console` of an online document ?

Comment: Yeah Its working :) .. But can I use the url mybasedomain.com/tab1 to load tab1 (reverse of above)

Comment: _"But can I use the url mybasedomain.com/tab1 to load tab1 (reverse of above)"_ ? Not certain interpret "to load tab1 (reverse of above) " correctly ? Is content of `tab1` set to `html` of  `"mybasedomain.com/tab1"` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93456/discussion-between-javvaji-kiran-and-guest271314).