# jQuery – Linking to page using data attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a simple dynamic tabbed gallery on page B using this code:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
     event.preventDefault();

     var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

     $('ul.tabs li > figcaption').removeClass('current');
     $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

     $(this).find('figcaption').addClass('current');
     $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
});
```

Suppose I have a link on page A that I want to link to page B with the corresponding tab on page B active. How would I go about doing that? I've been trying to research data attributes in href tags and I'm so confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the tab in the hash, like `page_b.html#tab1`. Then the script on page B can get `window.location.hash` and make that the current tab.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361536/change-url-of-the-windows-for-every-different-tab/33362303#33362303

Comment: So this is the code that determines what is current.

$(this).find('figcaption').addClass('current');
$("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

Should I save the hash into a variable? I'm kind of lost on how to implement that while preserving the current functionality.

Comment: You don't need to do anything to the current functionality. Just add code that runs when the page loads, that sets the current tab based on the page's hash.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unclear on what you mean by add code that runs when the page loads. Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the page hash to specify the initial tab of the page. So if you want `tab3` to be displayed, use a link like:

```
<a href="page_b.html#tab3">...</a>
```

On page B, check for the hash at page load time:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash) {
        $('ul.tabs li > figcaption, .tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(hash).addClass('current');
        $('ul.tabs li[data-tab=' + hash.substr(1) +'] figcaption').addClass('current');
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! A new piece of javascript that will be helpful in the future!